# Where do I define LD_LIBRARY_PATH so that Apache can see it?

Tags: apache2, python3, environment-variables, paths, ld

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.  I have defined this in my /etc/profile file

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/
```

I'm trying to figure out where I define the above so that Apache can see it.  Currently, when I go to start Apache, it dies with the error

```
$ sudo apachectl restart
apache2: Syntax error on line 146 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/wsgi.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: libpython3.9.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

which I suspect because it is not finding the above variable.  Where should the above be defined system wide?  Below is what "which apachectl" returns, if that matters ...

```
$ which apachectl
/usr/sbin/apachectl
```

**Edit:** Per what was asked in comments, line 146 of the apache.conf file is

```
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
```

I recently rebuilt mod_wsgi to use Python 3.9.  Python 3.9 requires this shared object library.

Comment: Fix the syntax error in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Comment: What does **line 146 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf** contain?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix  I added line 146 as an edit to the question

Comment: @Dave The edit was instrumental in writing my answer below. Please **double check** the link (from top to bottom) before picking one solution or the other. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

for PHP and oracle express do the following
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_env.html

for oracle linux  add this to /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
SetEnv LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/product/21c/dbhomeXE/lib/

error:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so (libclntsh.so.19.1: cannot open shared object file

Comment: Answer is not clear.